# How to Convert rawQuery() to query() with LIKE selectionArgs

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, sqlite

I want to select query for retrieving data from one table with two condition
my code is:

```
Cursor res = mDatabase.rawQuery("select * from " + tableName + " where " +colomn1+ " like '" + string1 + "and" + colomn2+ "like '" +string2+ "'", null);
```

I now that is not right, please help me

Comment: What do your table definitions look like and what data are you trying to query, exactly? What is it that's not right in the query currently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, it's best to use the [`query()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method, as it handles properly escaping the input.

In your case, it would be something like this:

```
Cursor res = mDatabase.query(tableName, 
     null, 
     colomn1 + " like ? and " + colomn2 + " like ?", 
     new String[]{string1, string2}, 
     null, null, null);
```